# Can't json_encode() an array or Laravel collection: "Type is not supported"

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I don't know what I'm doing wrong since it works with all the other models in the app. I refreshed and reseeded the database multiple times. The models extend the same abstract methods.

This is the code in the controller:

```
$substrates = $this->substrates->all()->toArray();
$temp = json_encode($substrates);
dd($temp, json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg(), $substrates);
```

This is the dd() output:

```
false
8
"Type is not supported"

array:119 [▼

  0 => array:21 [▼

    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Wood Free"
    "machine_id" => 2
    "classification" => "Cover"
    "origins" => "Coming Soon"
    "duplex" => true
    "color" => "Translucents"
    "texture" => "Leather"
    "finish" => "Felt"
    "product_type" => "Sheet"
    "caliper" => "0.06"
    "m_weight" => 70
    "width" => "46.40"
    "height" => "32.00"
    "pic" => stream resource @17 ▶}
    "price" => "0.30"
    "created_by" => 38
    "updated_by" => 16
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-01-27 08:00:11"
    "updated_at" => "2018-01-27 08:00:11"
  ]

  1 => array:21 [▶] ....
```

When I use JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR I get a json string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the error is the fact, that you're storing a **stream resource** in `pic` field of the serialised object that can't be serialised to JSON.

You can tell Eloquent model to skip selected attributes when they're converted to an array by setting a `$hidden` attribute in your model:

```
class Substrate extends Model {
  protected $hidden = ['pic'];
}
```

Comment: @MuntherJaber can you mark the question as answered?